# Input Repeat with same case

Tags: java, repeat

After I run this codes, it says BUILD SUCCESSFUL and it stops. What should I do to make it repeat to ask another input with same case? I did read tutorial on several web but I'm not helped by those.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwitchTry {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int mth;
    String mthString;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    mth =scanner.nextInt();

    switch (mth) {
        case 1: mthString = "January";
            break;
        case 2: mthString = "February";
            break;
        case 3: mthString = "March";
            break;
        case 4: mthString = "April";
            break;
        case 5: mthString = "May";
            break;
        case 6: mthString = "June";
            break;
        case 7: mthString = "July";
            break;
        case 8: mthString = "August";
            break;    
        case 9: mthString = "September";
            break;
        case 10: mthString = "October";
            break;
        case 11: mthString = "November";
            break;
        case 12: mthString = "December";
            break;    
        default: mthString = "Error";
            break;
    }

    System.out.println(mthString);
}

}
```

I appreciate any help that you can provide.

Comment: Use a `do-while` loop?

Comment: Do you at some point also want to break the loop? or keep asking forever?

Comment: No i guess, but idk @MadProgrammer

Comment: @Raf No, i want to make it asking forever.

Comment: See the answer all you need is do { your switch statement and print goes here } while (true);

Comment: @Raf yeah i did that thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I would try using a while loop to encase the switch. So it keeps asking your input. 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwitchTry {

public static void main(String[] args) {

while(true){
    int mth;
    String mthString;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    mth =scanner.nextInt();

    switch (mth) {
        case 1: mthString = "January";
            break;
        case 2: mthString = "February";
            break;
        case 3: mthString = "March";
            break;
        case 4: mthString = "April";
            break;
        case 5: mthString = "May";
            break;
        case 6: mthString = "June";
            break;
        case 7: mthString = "July";
            break;
        case 8: mthString = "August";
            break;    
        case 9: mthString = "September";
            break;
        case 10: mthString = "October";
            break;
        case 11: mthString = "November";
            break;
        case 12: mthString = "December";
            break;    
        default: mthString = "Error";
            break;
    }

    System.out.println(mthString);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working. I tried to type `while(false)` just to see what's gonna happen, but it says "unreacable statement", what happening?

Comment: while(false)  means the execution never reaches to the codes that resides inside the while block. The execution only enters inside while block when while (true)

Comment: Is there any idea we use `while(false)` in a coding? @Raf

Comment: We never use while(false). The reason there is while(true) is because it loops infinite number of times. while(false) loops zero times hence, the loop not being loop

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by *MadProgarmmer* do-while loop is the perfect use-case for such scenarios. You need to wrap your input line plus switch cases and print statement inside the do-while loop as follow:

```
do {
   //so you know that terminal is asking for input
   System.out.println("Input: "); 

   mth =scanner.nextInt();

   //copy/paste your switch case with last System.out.println() here

} while (true);
```

I am worried about having execution that never ends. Maybe you want to end the loop when the user supplies -1, so change the while(true) to while (mth != -1) and that should be your termination input.

Comment: Ouh now i prefer your idea than mine. Thanks.